# Problems installing netCDF4 with Ubuntu and running script Python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, netcdf, netcdf4

I am very new to Ubuntu and Python, but I need to run a script for modeling which involves netCDF4. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7,
I have followed this guide of how to install it, but when I try to run my script, it tells me 'No module named netCDF4'. I've tried to reinstall it but it still does not work. 
Please see the following two screenshots: 
[Successful installation of netCDF4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRBZB.png)

[No module named netCDF4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfZr0.png)

Any help will be much appreciated :) I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: looks like you need to install netcdf4-python too: http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/

Comment: You only compiled NetCDF, not Python-NetCDF. Why don't you install it using the Ubuntu package manager, or Pip?

Comment: Thank you  very much :) this helped